# ¿Cómo usar los métodos estáticos con @property?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Quiero crear una clase donde todos sus métodos serán estáticos.
Dentro de uno de los métodos estáticos hay una variable `NSMutableArray` que he definido con una `@property`.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *variable;`

El problema es que dentro de este método estático me da error al usar la variable con `self.variable`

Otro de los detalles es que antes de usar esta variable dentro del método estático necesito instanciarla con `alloc init` por lo que he pensado crear otro método estático llamado `init` que la instancie. No se si sería lo mas correcto.

Answer (score 1):

No es correcto usar métodos estáticos con propiedades.
Ya que las propiedades son self y self significa que has instanciado la clase.
Podrías usar el patrón singleton para solo iniciar la clase una vez. Aunque debes valorar si te es necesario usar un singleton o no ya que este estará instanciado todo el rato a no ser que lo mates manualmente.

Si vas a necesitar usar propiedades debes tener el objeto instanciado si o si.

Es más correcto aunque sea un objeto muy pequeño que lo instancies a que abuses de los métodos estáticos.